# How did the Half-Blood Prince invent Sectumsempra?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, said prince turned out to be the inventor of the many advanced dark spells written in its margins, including Sectumsempra.

How exactly did he do this? Was the process for how a spell is created for the first time (discovered?) ever elaborated on by Rowling?

Comment: Pretty sure Harry Potter doesn't need spoiler tags any more. (Apart from Hedwig)

Comment: @marcellothearcane Spoiler tags are not time-bound, there's meanwhile a whole new generation to read the books. But the question can be reqphrased to avoid spoilers first place

Comment: Voting to reopen since this question is about the specific spell's history, not the general process of creating custom spells (though the "dupe" does mention that spell as major example)